# How to allow safari through firewall windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, safari

I turn on my windows 7 firewall and was unable to search for option to allow safari access to internet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Typically you do not have to do anything within the Windows 7 Firewall to allow programs outbound access to the Internet.

Comment: I believe the original poster wanted to know how to allow outbound safari when windows firewall is set to "Block All" (not the default behavior, but I set it the same way). It is a problem since it seems the exe itself is not the one that makes the outbound connection.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`, create 2 rules (inbound/outgoing) point to Safari.exe and click to allow.

http://www.7tutorials.com/gain-additional-control-using-windows-firewall-advanced-security

Comment: You might consider putting some or most of the content from the link into your answer to prevent link rot.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, Safari is an outdated browser for Windows, you should install a new browser like Firefox, Google Chrome or Opera. And the Windows Firewall does not block your browser. You must have done something to the firewall itself. Tell us more.

Comment: Do you have anything to backup your claim that the desktop version of Safari is an outdate browser?

Comment: People, why the downvotes? @Ramhound: Are you serious? Safari for windows has been discontinued in 2012.